# Can I fully upgrade all weapons?

Tags: just-cause-2

By which I mean are there enough weapon parts in Panau to upgrade all black market weapons to level 6 (assuming vanilla game)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it will involve finding every weapon part, so it might take a long time.